# How do I remove unnecessary fills in an EAGLE polygon?

Tags: pcb, eaglecad, polygon

There are a lot of resistors and diodes on the board, where the polygon passes like this. How can I get rid of it?

[image]

Comment: Is there a reason why you want to remove this? Why do you mean that they are "unnecessary"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can draw on **41 tRestrict** and **42 bRestrict** to prevent the pour on those places.

Traces overlapping these layers will cause DRC violations.
The pour will keep the **isolate** distance in the polygon properties from the restrict layer objects.

Example:
[image]

Answer (score 4):

They are not redundant, it's really the whole point of a polygon pour: to reduce the impedance of the filled area. That said, a lot of people do it to be lazy (no judgement being made)..! Jereon's method is the scalpel blade approach (and the most correct). The hammer approach is to simply increase the "isolate" value of the polygon until it doesn't fill in between the pads of your components.